# PHP PDO when fetching data, can data be fetched into an Object which contains another Object?

Tags: php, object, pdo

Out of pure curiosity, can anyone quickly tell me if it is possible? I didn't implement it that way, but looking back, I wonder if it could be done. Here is the scenario:

A table of products, services and a relational table between the both defining costs

> ```
> Product ID |     Name
>    1       |   Product A
>    2       |   Product B
>
> Service ID |  Name
>    1       | Service A
>    2       | Service B
>    3       | Service C
>
> Price ID  |  Cost  | Product ID | Service ID
>     1     |  1     |     1      |    1
>     2     |  2     |     1      |    3
>     3     |  3     |     2      |    2
>     4     |  4     |     2      |    3
> ```

So if there were Table Data Objects, there would be:

- Class Product with attributes: id, name, array of Services.
- Class Service has attributes: id, name, cost

---

```
 //$query = obtain a list of all products with services and prices;
 //$query = obtain a product and all it's associated services and prices; 
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $statement -> execute();
 $results = $statement ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,"Product");
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO does not seem to have support for nesting any relational data into a given object. Have a look at the documentation of [fetch](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php). You could probably build the logic required to load the relations of a product into the Product class itself and invoke it manually.

As PDO injects the values of the class properties prior to `__construct()` you might be able to pull off some voodoo magic within the constructor, I'm not too sure of that though.

Either way, this is typically one of those things a solid ORM layer can provide you with. And [some](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) [are](http://xyster.libreworks.com/) [out](http://redbeanphp.com/) [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony).

Comment: Thank you Marco. Yeah this was not done yesterday. I actually was just viewing the project online and this scenario popped into my head again and I thought I would put it out here. I will most definitely check out your links. :)

Comment: Glad to be of any help. Oh, and lest we forget the beautiful [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)!